# Circular Buffer Comparison / Lookup Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, buffer, circular-buffer

I want to detect if a circular buffer is a mirror, or rotation, of a list of other buffers, of the same length.

For example given the following 3 buffers:

```
AAABCCCA
AABCCBAA
AAAACCAA
```

Then:
`CCBAAAAC` would match, as it is a mirrored rotation of the first buffer.

Currently I simply compare every buffer in every rotation, then reverse the buffer and do it all again.

This requires:
`2*n*i` buffer comparisons.
(Where n is number of buffers to compare two, and i is the length of the buffer).

Does anyone know a faster algorithm?

The list to compare against grows (as I find one not in the list I had it). Is there a method where I can somehow 'order' buffers, so that comparisons can be done faster?

One idea I had was to also store a sorted version of each buffer, so that you can quickly compare if the same number of items exist.

But is there are more general solution to somehow order by 'circular sequence'?

Comment: double up search pattern, then look for exact match in it. ??

Comment: That is essentially the same thing as I have said. The pattern matching would look in i places across n strings, and you would have to do it backwards, for 2*n*i. However what you have said is the easiest way to code it using standard functions like strstr etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each buffer, you could rotate it until it has the minimum lexicographical value.

For example, your example buffers could be rotated like this:

```
AAABCCCA -> AAAABCCC
AABCCBAA -> AAAABCCB
AAAACCAA -> AAAAAACC
```

This basically means putting the lowest-valued item first.  If there is a tie, compare the next items, etc.  This gives a unique ordering for any pattern.

Comment: Wow. I don't know why I didn't realise this. To many buffers spinning around in my head. I can do that, then order order them lexicographically, which means i could do a binary search. The number of buffer comparisons would then be down from 2*i*n to log(n).

Comment: You could store/lookup the minimum lexicographical value between the rotated original and the rotated mirror, rather than storing both. @Myforwik It would be `i log n` not just `log n`. I think you could use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)-like structure to get down to `O(i)`.

Comment: @Myforwik Oh, "buffer comparisons". Then `log n` is correct. The Trie is i.t.o character comparisons, not buffer comparisons. A more common way would be to count character comparisons instead.